# Find the length of the curve.

Tags: integration, derivatives, curves

Let $x(t) = \sin(t)^4$, $y(t) = \cos(t)^2$, $t \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

We want to find this curve's length.

There lots of these type questions, but I have a problem with just counting an answer :

Here's what I know:
$l = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}{\rm d}t$

$x'(t) = 4\sin^3(t)\cos(t), y'(t) = -2\cos(t)\sin(t)$

We substitute the resulting into the formula:
$l = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{16\sin^6(t)\cos^2(t) + 4\cos^2(t)\sin^2(t)}{\rm d}t = $

$= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\cos(t)\sin(t)\sqrt{4\sin^4(t) + 1}{\rm d}t$

But what can I do next to get an answer ? I don't know any technique for this. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $s=4\sin^{2}t+1$. You get $\frac 1  4 \int_1^{5}\sqrt {s}ds$.

EDIT. It should have been $\sqrt {4\sin^{4}t+1}$ inside the integral instead of $\sqrt {4\sin^{2}t+1}$. So you have to make the substitution $s=4\sin^{4}t+1$ and use the fact that $\sin^{2}t= \sqrt {\frac {s-1} 4}$.

Comment: Can you explain how we get this? What we gonna do with $2sin(t)cos(t)$ when substitute?
Also there was a mistake (we need $sin^4(t)$)

Comment: Try to do by hand the substitution, you will directly see where goes $2\sin(t)\cos(t)$.

Comment: @Someone What is the derivative of $4\sin^{2}+1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy seems like $16\sin^3(t)\cos(t)$ (P.S it was a mistake in question and looks like I have to substitute $s = 4\sin^4(t) + 1$, right?)

Comment: @Someone You are right. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Substitute $u = 4\sin^2(x) + 1$.